# Program started through the Windows Task Scheduler doesn't listen on port

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-tasks

Windows 2008r2

I have a legacy application, which when it is run listens on a port. When I execute the application, it works fine. When I run it through a scheduled task, it starts the process, but does not listen on the port (`netstat -ao`). It is using the same user account I am logged in as for the task user.

Any ideas why it won't listen on the port?

Thanks.

Comment: I understand it's the same user account, but does that account have administrative privileges? do you get a UAC prompt when you run it normally? if so I would double-check the "Run with highest privileges" option in the task, or trying playing with the other security options

Comment: The account is a member of the administrators group, and I don't get the prompt. Thanks.

Comment: This turned out to be a licensing issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!